# the difference in results by different data types in python

Tags: python

my python file like below, but I don't know why the result is difference, 
the only difference is about z&k , z is int and k is str.

```
l = []
j = []
for x in range(100,1000):
    for y in range(100,1000):
        z = (x * y)
        k = str(x*y)

        if k == k[::-1]:
            '''print (k)
            print('========================')'''
            l.append(k)
        if str(z) == str(z)[::-1]:
            '''print (z)
            print ('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++')'''
            j.append(z)

print('*********************************************')
print max(l)
print max(j)
print (l)
```

Comment: The `if` statements are asking the question "is this a palindrome?" -- is it the same when reversed?

Answer (score 3):

`l` contains strings, `j` contains integers.

So in the case of `l`, `max` performs *lexicographic* comparison (ignoring numerical value, regular string comparison in this case) whereas in `j`, `max` works as intended by taking the maximum integer.

```
>>> "99999" > "906609"
True
```

aside: you can compute the maximum value in one line using nested comprehensions passed to `max`:

```
max(i for i in (x*y for x in range(100,1000) for y in range(x,1000)) if str(i)==str(i)[::-1])
```

(note that there's no need to start from `100` for the inner loop, starting from `x` is enough since multiplication is commutative)